# WordPress Bootstrap nav menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap, menu

Хочу поправить меню в моб версии, чтобы оно открывалось внизу, а не с левой стороны. Делаю все на bootstrap. Код вот, фото тоже.

```
  <body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="wptime-plugin-preloader"></div>
<div class="linkcolor">
<header id="masthead" class="site-header">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/o-kompanii/">WEB-DEV </a>
        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/vodafone-e1499432943704.png" />(095)-169-52-92    
        <br>
        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/ksm-e1499431932955.png" />(068)-486-43-00
        </div>

        <div class="forp"><a href="/svjaz-so-mnoj/" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button">Обсудить задачу</a></div>
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">      
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" >
        <?php esc_html_e( 'МЕНЮ', 'mycoreadap' ); ?>
        </button>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <div class="nav navbar-nav">
            <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                    'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
                ) );

                ?></div></div>
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    </div>
    </div>
</header><!-- #masthead -->
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ссылку поправил, вот мой сайт http://webdev.romny.info/
Меню исправить не получается

Comment: Изменил код, залил новый

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в style.css

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
    clear: both;
}

.main-navigation li {
    float: none;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: отлично работает!

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый зеленой галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.